# Shape of a transform matrix that maps $\mathbb{R}^{a \times b}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{c \times d}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, tensors, transformation

I'm looking for the dimension of some tensor $T$ that transforms $a \times b$ matrices to $c \times d$ matrices. I initially thought it would have to be of a greater dimension, perhaps some shape like $a\times b\times c \times d$ since transforming m vector to a n vector would require a $n \times m$ matrix.

However, I can't seem to think how it would look like aside from doing the normal matrix multiplication but by dotting matrices instead of vectors.

What would be the dimensions of this $a \times b$ to $c \times d$
transform look like?

Comment: The title makes it look like you want a map between cross products, not matrices of the given shapes.

Comment: FWIW map in question would pertain to the vector space $\left(\mathbb{k}^{b}\to\mathbb{k}^{a}\right)\to\left(\mathbb{k}^{d}\to\mathbb{k}^{c}\right)\ \simeq\ \left(\mathbb{k}^{a}\right)^{\vee}\otimes \mathbb{k}^{b}\otimes \mathbb{k}^{c}\otimes\left(\mathbb{k}^{d}\right)^{\vee}$, with $\mathbb{k}$ the field over which you’re working and $(-)^{\vee}$ dualization. So the dimension is numerically correct.

Comment: @J.G. I'm using the convention that appears in other related titles. How should I amend it?

Comment: Could you link to any examples of such titles? I'm surprised if it's common.

Comment: @J.G. Just looking at the related questions sidebar, I see a post with $n \times k$ post. On the wikipedia pages, [like this one on transform matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix), they write $m \times n$ on the first two paragraphs. Also, people usually state the space as $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.